openapi-generator-cli axios client, getting SyntaxError: The requested module X does not provide an export named 'PokemonApi'
I generated an Axios Typescript client for the PokeAPI using OpenAPI Generator with the following command:
npx openapi-generator-cli generate -i https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/pokeapi/master/openapi.yml -g typescript-axios -o ./src

It generated a folder, containing an index.ts file which exports everything:
export * from './api';
export * from './configuration';

I added the index.ts to be the main in my package.json of the  custom Turborepo package:
{
  "name": "@repo/poke-client",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "./src/index.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "codegen:pokeapi": "openapi-generator-cli generate -i https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/pokeapi/master/openapi.yml -g typescript-axios -o ./src"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@openapitools/openapi-generator-cli": "^2.13.4"
  }
}


Importing also looks good in the IDE:

But when I run it (using tsx), I get the following error:
backend:dev: SyntaxError: The requested module '@repo/poke-client' does not provide an export named 'PokemonApi'
backend:dev:     at ModuleJob._instantiate (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:131:21)
backend:dev:     at async ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:213:5)
backend:dev:     at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:316:24)
backend:dev:     at async loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:34:7)
backend:dev:     at async handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:66:12)

I did manage to find a workaround, using it like this:
import * as pokeClient from '@repo/poke-client';

const api = new pokeClient.default.PokemonApi();

But it leads to weird TypeScript and ESlint errors on every line that uses this (although compiling and working):
backend:lint:    2:7   error  'api' is assigned a value but never used             @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
backend:lint:    3:7   error  'POKEMONS_COUNT' is assigned a value but never used  @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
backend:lint:   13:19  error  Unreachable code                                     no-unreachable

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Apparently, the problem was that in the package.json of my internal package in Turborepo.
I added this:
"type": "module"

And it worked!
